# Return from EventListener on web worker

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

I am having problems returning data from data that is passed back from a web worker.

I want to return `ret` after i get a 'return' message back from the worker and execute the `Bar` function.

```
Test.prototype.Foo = function () {
    var that = this;
    var ret;

    this.worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) 
    {
        switch (e.data.cmd) 
        {
            ...
            case 'return':
                ret = that.Bar();
                that.worker.terminate();
                break;
        }
    }, false);

    that.worker.postMessage({"cmd":"start"});

    console.log(ret);
    return ret;
};
```

Comment: event listener callbacks are not called right when you set them, the listener is set and then the code continues on so you return before the worker is done. You need to pass the data from inside the listener to another function

Comment: The point of web workers is that they execute  without blocking the main thread. How can it assign the value before the `return` if it's non-blocking?

Comment: It does not work because of the asynchronious call of the webworker function. You have to restructure your code.

Comment: I guess I'll add a callback function then.

Thanks for the Help.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you'd use the callback function?